# Label in ListView not binding on Collection Clear

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, data-binding

I have a Xamarin form with a listview. In the view cell I have a label and an Entry which are bound to 2 properties on an object in an observable collection.

When I first load the form and add to the collection this works fine. Then I call Collection Clear(). Then I add a new item to the collection and the Entry shows but the Label does not. But if I change the label to an Entry then it works.

Also, if I add a second item to the collection the label on the second and successive items also display. It is just the first one after calling Clear().

Am I missing something special for a label?

This is the data template in the xaml form

```
<DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid HeightRequest="60">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Text="{Binding UpcName}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" 
                               Text="{Binding Quantity}" 
                               Grid.Column="1" 
                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                               WidthRequest="40"
                               VerticalOptions="Center" 
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <customControls:ExtendedButton Text="DEL" 
                            Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteInventoryCommand, Source={x:Reference UpcListView}}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                            Style="{StaticResource SmallDestrutiveButtonStyle}"
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            FontSize="12"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
```

and this is the property it is bound to

```
        var inventory = new InventoryItemVM
        {
            Id = upcDetail.Id,
            Upc = upcDetail.UPC,
            UpcName = upcDetail.Name,
            Quantity = 1,
            BrandImage = upcDetail.BottleImage
        };

        Inventories.Add(inventory);
```

later I call

```
Inventories.Clear();
```

Then next time I add the inventory the label does not show the UpcName. But add a second one and it does for that one. Or change the label for an Entry and it works every time.

Any ideas please?

UPDATE AND FIX:
If anyone else has this issue, it is to do with the label sizing (or more specifically NOT resizing on content change).

When I removed an item or cleared the list the label bound to a null value and set it's width to 0. Then when the content changed, it did not resize (I dont see a way to get it to resize - so if someone knows, please let me know).

The way around this was to set the FallbackValue on the label (e.g. Uknown) and set the labels HorizontalOptions to fill. Then it worked.

So it was always binding correctly but not rendering correctly.

Comment: my guess is your collection clear method is not working as it should've can you just give my idea a try instead of calling the collection Clear method just initialize a new one something like `Inventories= new ObservableCollection<InventoryItemVM>();`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably debause of the mode of the binding :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode

Entry have a two way mode by default, and label does not, so you can't change it's content from the Viewmodel without specifying that you will.

you should try with

```
 <Label Text={Binding Upcname, Mode=TwoWay}/>
```

I hope this helps.